# Can't use iterative variable as part specification

Tags: iteration, sets, index, array

I've got the following mathematica code:

```
CreateKinMatrix[d_, n_, x_] := (A = ConstantArray[0, {n, d, d}]; 
  Do[A[[u, All, All]] = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]], 
   Do[Do[A[[u, j, k]] = 
      If[k == j, 1, 
       If[Min[k, j] == 1, 
        x*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], 
        RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]] , {k, 1, d}], {j,
      1, d}], {u, 1, n}]; Return[A];)
```

with which I'm trying to create n d*d matrices in an array. However, mathematica gives me the error

```
"Set::pkspec1: The expression u cannot be used as a part specification."
```

Can anybody tell me WHY this is and HOW I can fix it, after all I can use the variables j,k as part specification in litteraly the same way, but somehow it does not work for u.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please provide the code which gave that error too!

Answer (score 3):

For the simple answer, you need to change the line

`A[[u, All, All]] = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]],`

to

`A[[u, All, All]] = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]];`

The semicolon is necessary here to suppress output, and the comma should not be there as the next command is another `Do[` loop (which is still part of the outer `Do` loop's first argument).

---

You don't have to read this part, but I think it could greatly improve your Mathematica experience if you move away from iterative loops like `Do`. There are times where it is unavoidable, but I think it's a bad idea to use `Do` in Mathematica, especially when there are several nested levels of `Do`; this is not an argument from a performance perspective, but from a readability perspective. All of the closing brackets can make it difficult to follow, and it creates a situation in which it is both easy to make an error, and hard to catch one.

Let's first examine the structure of `CreateKinMatrix`, and then see if we can write it in a more Mathematica-esque way.

### Outer (u) loop

Let's first look at the outer `Do` loop on its first pass with `u=1`. We'll assign some values for `d` and `n` as well:

```
d = 3;
n = 2;
A = ConstantArray[0, {n, d, d}];
u=1;
```

Observe the dimensions of A[[u]] are `{d,d}`:

```
A[[u]] // Dimensions
(*{3,3}*)
```

Now the code assigns:

```
A[[u, All, All]] = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]];
```

this is also the same as (I will use this form from now on as I think it's easier to understand):

```
A[[u, All, All]] = IdentityMatrix[n];
```

Since `n!=d` in our example, Mathematica assumes you want to assign every element in `A[[u]]` to be `IdentityMatrix[n]`:

```
A[[u]]
(*
{{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, {{{1, 0}, {0,
     1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}, {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1,
     0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}}
*)
```

so `A[[u]]` is a `d` x `d` array where each element is an `IdentityMatrix[n]`

(note if `n==d`, then `A[[u]]` just ends up being a single `IdentityMatrix[n]`)

### Inner (j and k) loops

Next the code goes into the `k` `Do` loop and then into the `j` loop.

As we just saw `A[[1,j,k]]` is equal to `IdentityMatrix[n]` for `1<j<d&&1<k<d`

```
A[[1,1,1]]
(*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}*)
```

But now we reassign:

```
A[[u, j, k]] = 
 If[k == j,
         1, 
         If[Min[k, j] == 1,
                         x*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], 
                         RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]
           ]
   ]
```

*Notice all the `If` conditions only depend on k and j, and not on any values in A*

This part is saying "create a `d` x `d` `IdentityMatrix` (since 1s on the diagonals when `j==k`) and replace the elements **off the main diagonal** with:

**1.** x times a random real between 0 and 1 (`x*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]`) If the element is in the first row or column (`Min[k, j] == 1`)

**2.** a random real (`RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]`) between 0 and 1 otherwise.

Since these conditions have no dependence on the actual values of `A`, we can create a much simpler implementation.

### Simpler implementation

First notice that both conditions **1.** and **2.** need a random real between 0 and 1. We can combine this into one step by sampling a `{d,d}` random matrix, and taking the elementwise `Max` (at the lowest level) between the random reals and the identity matrix of dimension `d`; this makes sense since the random numbers are between 0 and 1, so `Max` will return either:

- 1 if we are on the diagonal (where the identity matrix is 1)
- the value of the random matrix at that position if we are off the diagonal (where the identity matrix is 0):

```
id = IdentityMatrix[d];
randUniformMat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {d, d}];
lowestLevel = TensorRank@id;
oneOnDiagsAndRandomElseWhere = 
  MapThread[Max, {id, randUniformMat}, lowestLevel];
```

And then we can implement the `x` multiplication of condition **2.** by creating a matrix that is `x` in the first row and column (except on the diagonal at `[[1,1]]` where it is 1), and 1 everywhere else:

```
xMat = ConstantArray[1, {d, d}];
xMat[[All, 1]] = x;
xMat[[1, All]] = x;
xMat[[1, 1]] = 1;
```

and then we multiply `xMat` with `oneOnDiagsAndRandomElseWhere` to get our output.

Notice we can extend this to an `{n,d,d}` matrix also by just mapping the multiplication of `xMat` acrosss all `n` parts of `oneOnDiagsAndRandomElseWhere`:

```
CreateKinMatrixNEW[d_, n_, x_] :=
 (
  id = ConstantArray[IdentityMatrix[d], n];
  randUniformMat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, d, d}];

  lowestLevel = TensorRank@id;
  oneOnDiagsAndRandomElseWhere = 
   MapThread[Max, {id, randUniformMat}, lowestLevel];

  xMat = ConstantArray[1, {d, d}];
  xMat[[All, 1]] = x;
  xMat[[1, All]] = x;
  xMat[[1, 1]] = 1;

  xMat*# & /@ oneOnDiagsAndRandomElseWhere
  )
```

Comparing the output to the original (slightly fixed) function, we see they are the same (differing only by the random numbers):

```
CreateKinMatrix[d_, n_, x_] :=
 (
  A = ConstantArray[0, {n, d, d}];
  Do[
   A[[u, All, All]] = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]];
   Do[
    Do[
     A[[u, j, k]] = 
      If[k == j, 1, 
       If[Min[k, j] == 1, 
        x*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], 
        RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]],
     {k, 1, d}],
    {j, 1, d}],
   {u, 1, n}];
  A)
```

```
CreateKinMatrix[3, 2, x] // MatrixForm
CreateKinMatrixNEW[3, 2, x] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We also see a performance improvement (using d=100, n=200 as a test here):

```
CreateKinMatrix[100, 200, x]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
CreateKinMatrixNEW[100, 200, x]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*"
4.70644
0.725346
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a semi-colon instead of a comma after

```
A[[u, All, All]] = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]]
```

Specifically

```
CreateKinMatrix[d_, n_, x_] :=
  (A = ConstantArray[0, {n, d, d}];
   Do[
     A[[u, All, All]] = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]];(* <------ HERE *)
     Do[
       Do[
         A[[u, j, k]] = If[k == j, 1, If[Min[k, j] == 1, x*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]]], 
         {k, 1, d}],
       {j, 1, d}],
     {u, 1, n}];
   Return[A];)
```